# Array index is name of defined constant instead of value

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the following define in my code

`define('SERVICE', 1);`

When I now initialize an array like this

`$serviceLimit[SERVICE_PAGECHECK][0] = 0;`

and now do a `var_dump` on `$serviceLimit` in my mind it should output it like this

```
array (size=1)
  '0' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 0
```

However, it currently looks like this

```
array (size=1)
  'SERVICE' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 0
```

How can this be? Why is the array index using the name of the variable rather than the value?

Comment: http://ideone.com/71vEp2 The notice shown should explain exactly what is happening

Comment: What is the constant SERVICE_PAGECHECK set to?

Comment: Perhaps http://ideone.com/YPEAui is what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems strange, because of using 2 different constants: `SERVICE` and `SERVICE_PAGECHECK`. Just correct the constant name.